# Regex to match url but not urlMvc

Tags: regex

I'm going through my Android app at the minute making sure all my HTTP calls point to the same place. I want to run a search so I don't have to manually look through each file and possibly miss one. I've seen I can do a find using Regex. What I need is a url that matches the string `url` but ignores `urlMvc` and `urlProcedural` (as there the variables the calls should be made to). Is this something thats possible with a Regex or will I have to go through all the files manually?

Comment: You can use negative lookahead: `url(?!Mvc|Procedural)`

Comment: Yes, I believe it's possible through regex :) @UlugbekUmirov's solution is likely solve your issue. What are you using to search through your files (Sublime, Eclipse...)? There are different regex flavors depending on the tool/language.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, so essentially Intellij.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov that worked perfect :). Post it as an answer and I'll accept it for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy from comment: You can use negative lookahead: `url(?!Mvc|Procedural)`